Automated parskip after formulas
I understand that English people generally want to delete paragraph indentation everywhere... This is not the french custom, and I there is very few tips on how to add indentation in LaTeX. Hence my question ^^
For now, every time I write a formula between \[ , \], I write \par juste after that so that the newt paragraph is not glued to the margin of my page. I'd like that to be automated, that's all.
Same problem with center environment (but I could just renew the center environment to add this \par, if I wanted).

Just leave an empty line after \]

BTW it's not that "we English" (I'm not) want to delete paragraph indentation. An indentation is perfectly fine - at the start of a paragraph. However, if the text following a formula (or a center environment , or... ) still logically belongs to the same paragraph, then the indentation is wrong. Last time I spoke to French colleagues on this subject, they agreed (at least on this point :-)).

Thanks ! It will do the trick for now. Concerning paragraph identation, it is all explained in Le bon usage, Grevisse - the reference for good usage in France ;)

"I understand that English people generally want to delete paragraph indentation everywhere."  no:-)  But the text after a display math doesn't form a new paragraph. Often it is not even the start of a new sentence.

It is definitely a logical division in English writing, as opposed to a pure function of typography.

Paragraph skip and indentation are different things. You're probably referring to the latter (alinéa in French, I believe).
In the first half of the 20th century it became fashionable, particularly in German speaking countries, to replace indentation with vertical space. Such practice was (and still is) in business letters, but not for typographic choice, rather because doing a double return was easier with typewriters than doing indentation. You see that the practice is still common by just looking at the posts here, where paragraph skip is employed.
However, most prominent typographers, even some who had endorsed the practice, came to reject it: the name that comes to mind is Jan Tschichold, who wrote an essay on “Why should paragraphs be indented”. after having promoted, in his younger years, paragraph skip.
Anyway, it's not really true that English or American typography tries to remove indentation “everywhere”. It's common that paragraphs after titles are not indented, because in that case the indentation serves no purpose.
Your problem seems to be about indentation after displays. The solution is simple. There are two cases:

the text after the display belongs to the same paragraph as the display;
the text after the display starts a new paragraph.

The case depends on the particular situation, so there's no general rule.
In case 1 there should be no indentation, in case 2 there should.
The way to get indentation is the standard one: leave a blank line in the input file.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

The text after the following display will not be indented, because no blank line appears after the display. We have proved that
\[
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}
\]
and we're very happy. The text goes on without indentation, because it's part of the paragraph.

The text after the following display will be indented, because a blank line appears after the display. We finally proved that
\[
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}.
\]

Improper integrals have several uses but they should used with care. Here the text is indented, because a new paragraph has started.

\end{document}


Note that indenting the text after the first display would be wrong in any country and language.

I was told that the no-indentation-after-titles was an Americanism and understood they should be indented in British English. But I don't know if that's true.

@cfr Possibly. According to Tschichold, only paragraphs after a centered title should not be indented. All others should.

@cfr  Bringhurst also advocated no indentation after a heading, as it is obvious you starting a new paragraph. With more documents being published online my own advice for paragraphs is to indent + adjust parskip as it makes it easier to read online as users are expecting similar experiences to websites.

@yannisl Online publishing has different needs than paper publishing. Paragraph skip on printed books is just a waste of paper and doesn't contribute to readability.

A lot of stuff has the same layout for online and paper, though. For books and articles, the online version is generally just the PDF and formatting is identical to the printed copy. But I tend to think of PDF as distinct from online/web anyway, so it seems reasonable to follow printed conventions there.

@cfr  I am talking about reading pdfs online. Most people do these days with the exception of perhaps very few papers that they find more convenient to have them printed. I am also talking of an extra 1pt or so on the normal skip, anything higher you might as well go to block paragraphs. On readability I dont have any citations either way, other than my own experience as I get older.

@yannisl Then you have to do the same for hard copy because the pagination etc. has to be the same. I'm not sure I really have any experience of increases that small. But I prefer lines to be more spaced out than standard anyway. (I have trouble scanning back across to pick up the next line. Not age-related. My eyes don't work together.)
